# Offsetting 100 ft from line feature while editing in ArcMap?

Tags: arcmap, editing, cogo, offset

I have the ArcGIS 10.6 advanced lisense. I am trying to offset a line feature using the editor tool. I know that I can do it in COGO, but how to set the unit as ft. In COGO, the offset unit option is not there.

Comment: Copy parallel in editing mode.

Comment: But it doesn't have the unit. I don't know if it's offsetting based on meter, feet or point

Comment: Look at your coordinate system or simply try one and measure distance. In any case you can undo or stop editing without saving.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way is with the ["Copy Parallel" tool.](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/editing-fundamentals/copying-parallel-line-features.htm) 
While editing and you have the feature selected, just click the editing toolbar dropdown and select copy parallel.  You'll then enter the distance, side, and type of offset.